# Named pipe swallowing first field of Linux command output

Tags: bash, scripting, named-pipes

I'm trying to parse the output of the Linux df tool for use in a machine status report. I'm using almost identical code to parse the output of the ps tool and it works fine (all fields are available in read loop) but in the code below the first field output from awk (percentUsed) is missing when I read from the named pipe.

```
#!/bin/sh

mkfifo dfPipe0
IFS=" "
df -h | awk '{ print $6" "$3" "$7" "$1 }' > dfPipe0 &
while read -r percentUsed size mountedOn fileSystem
do
  printf "%s\n" "${percentUsed} | ${size} | ${mountedOn} | ${fileSystem}"
done < dfPipe0
rm dfPipe0
```

Sample df + awk output

```
$ df -h | awk '{ print $6" "$3" "$7" "$1 }'
Use% Size Mounted Filesystem
0% 1.9G /dev devtmpfs
- 0 /sys/kernel/security securityfs
4% 1.9G /dev/shm tmpfs
$
```

Comment: Why are you using a named pipe instead of just piping to the `while` loop?

Comment: Why do you need `awk`? `df -h | while read -r filesystem size used avail percentUsed mountedOn`

Comment: Check your script to make sure there are no `\r` characters in it.

Comment: Please include the output of the first script.

Comment: fwiw ... I cat'd the `df/awk` output (from the question) into `dfPipe0` and the provided code works as expected (ie, no missing fields)

Comment: Looks like you simply printed the wrong fields in awk. I cannot reproduce your sample output for `df -h | awk '{ print $6" "$3" "$7" "$1 }'`. My df prints the header `Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on`. awk then turns this into `Mounted Used on Filesystem`. Note that `$7` is always empty, since `Mounted on` is supposed to be one column. There is no data for `on` alone.

Comment: @Socowi I posted a similar comment, but deleted it because the sample output shows that `$6` is `Use%`. I guess it depends on the version of `df`.

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks. That got me thinking about my environment and I have a df alias in my .bashrc but I don't think those are called in scripts. I removed it and it had no effect.

Comment: I tried using a standard pipe as @Barmar suggested (code below) and it works fine. I'll see how to close this question.
df -h | \
while read -r fileSystem size used avail percentUsed mountedOn
do  printf "%s\n" "$fileSystem | $size | $used | $avail | $percentUsed | $mountedOn"
done

Comment: I added my own answer because there were no answers to this question (thought the comments resolved my issue) and the StackOverflow docs said this is a way to close this issue. @Barmar resolved my issue so if he wants to format his suggestion as an answer, I'll accept that answer. Otherwise I'll accept the one I wrote once I'm able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my code to use the standard pipe suggestion by @Barmar and it resolves my problem. The code below works fine.

```
df -h | \
while read -r fileSystem size used avail percentUsed mountedOn
do  printf "%s\n" "$fileSystem | $size | $used | $avail | $percentUsed | $mountedOn"
done
```